# Try statement not executing - goes straight to catch

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, try-catch

I am setting up a `winform` that takes the first name, last name, and student ID of a student into an `sql` database named `college`, and performs a stored procedure which searches for that student, then displays the results in a `DataGridView` when the search button is pressed. Whenever I press the search button I get the following error

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Search2.exe".

My program is skipping over the `Try` block shown, and going to the `Catch` statement. Can anyone tell me why this is?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Search2
{
    public partial class frmSearch : Form
    {
        public frmSearch()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string studid, fname, lname;

            try
            {
                // get the values
                fname = txtFname.Text.Trim();
                lname = TxtLname.Text.Trim();
                studid = txtStudentID.Text.Trim();

                //instantiate datatier
                Class1 astudent = new Class1();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                ds = astudent.GetStudents(studid, fname, lname);

                // populate the datagrid with dataset
                dgvStudents.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        private void frmSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'collegeDataSet.STUDENT' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            //this.sTUDENTTableAdapter.Fill(this.collegeDataSet.STUDENT);

        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Search2
{
    class Class1: frmSearch
    {
        static String connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=EVEDELL17;Initial Catalog=College;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString;
        static SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmdString = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();

        public DataSet GetStudents(string studid, string fname, string lname)
        {
            try
            {
                // Open Connection
                myConn.Open();
                //clear command argument
                cmdString.Parameters.Clear();
                //command
                cmdString.Connection = myConn;
                cmdString.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmdString.CommandTimeout = 1500;
                cmdString.CommandText = "SearchStudent";
                // define input parameter

                cmdString.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1).Value = fname;
                cmdString.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = lname;
                // adapter and daraset
                SqlDataAdapter aAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                aAdapter.SelectCommand = cmdString;
                DataSet aDataSet = new DataSet();
                // fill adapter
                aAdapter.Fill(aDataSet);
                //return Dataset
                return aDataSet;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                myConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You got an exception, but you swallow it. Never do that. This is a cardinal sin of exception handling. At least expose the result of the Exception in a message box: `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());` | Ideall also post result of ToString() here. It will include inner Exceptions and the stack trace, about 95% of the Exceptions information.

Comment: For general rules about exception handling, I have these two articles I link often. They got most people up to speed: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. I am under the assumption that the code should hit the try block, and should not be hitting the exception.

Comment: You do not "hit" excpetions. They are thrown and then caught. And they can be thrown by *every* piece of code. And wee need the full exception details to help you.

Comment: I was under the assumption that, since the program goes straight to the catch without executing the try statement with breakpoints on, that the try statement is not being used.

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=EVEDELL17;Initial Catalog=College;Integrated Security=True"]` is returning `null` because you don't have a connection string by that ***name***, so accessing the `ConnectionString` property throws NRE. The indexer parameter is supposed to be the name, not an actual connection string.

Comment: That makes sense, but if that is the case, where am I to put the connection string? I already have one in appConfig.

Comment: @pmbaseball1 The catch belongs to the try as much as the else belongs to a if. | I agree with Xanders answer: THis sounds like an issue when setting the static values.

Comment: The one in app.config has a name. Use that name as the string in the square brackets here. That will *look up* the value from app.config.

Comment: I have fixed that issue. This is the portion of code that is being skipped over during debugging. DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                ds = astudent.GetStudents(studid, fname, lname);

                // populate the datagrid with dataset
                dgvStudents.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

Comment: Can you step into the constructor at `new Class1()`? If you can, the problem extends into `InitializeComponent` in `frmSearch`. If not, you haven't fully resolved the problems in your type initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xander got the answer I think: Something goes "bump" when initializing those static fields. And static/type constructors are notoriously poor at communicating exceptions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typeinitializationexception

The underlying problem however, is one of pattern. And there are several issues. However you can often fudge these parts for simple learning examples.

**Disposeable**

SqlConnectons is Disposeable, as it contains some unmanaged resources. Always dispose of disposeables. My personal rule is:

- never split the Creation and Disposing of a Disposeable resource. Create, Use, Dispose. All in the same piece of code - ideally using a [using statement/block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).
- The rare exception is if you wrap around something disposeable that you can not Dispose (or even just might ocassionally). In that case implent the Dispose pattern yourself, with the sole purpose of relaying the Dispose() call. (Approxmialtey 95% of all classes are only Disposeable because of this).

**Avoid Globals/Static**

Static variables are global variables. And quicklly after inventing those, we realized that using either was a terrible idea 90% of the time. *Particular* for exchanging/sharing data.

While I go even a bit further, never have a field that is static and can be written. `constant` and `readonly` (runtime constants) should be the only statics you ever use. If you can not make it that, do not make it static. Stuff like connection strings are way up on that rule. If you can not tag it like that, *do not make it a static to begin with*.

At tops I make a class, struct or tupple. And assign a instance of it to a static readonly/constant variable. Stuff like connection strings are either a instance variable, or handed in on each call of a function like `GetStudents`. Indeed, Class1 looks a lot like a DB access abstraction. And those in particular fall under the "do not make static" rule.

Comment: So, the initialization of connString, myConn, and cmdString should not be static? If so where should I move them to, or how should i initialize them. Should I make them public? Or should I perhaps move them into GetStudents method?

Comment: I have upgraded to visual studio 19, and now have a more detailed exception: " A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)"

Comment: Problem has been resolved.. StudentID field was not named correctly. Found this by upgrading to vs2012.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the exception type--`TypeInitializationException`--I suspect the problem is with the static field initializers:

```cs
static String connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=EVEDELL17;Initial Catalog=College;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString;
static SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmdString = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
```

Those initializers will run the first time their containing class (`Class1`) is "touched" by the runtime. Because they aren't in a method, it's hard for the compiler to give a helpful stack trace when they fail. Try replacing the inline initializers with a static constructor:

```cs
static String connString;
static SqlConnection myConn;
static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmdString;

static Class1() {
    connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=EVEDELL17;Initial Catalog=College;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString;
    myConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    cmdString = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
}
```

I think you'll get a better error message that way. You can also set a breakpoint in the constructor to see exactly what happens during initialization.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typeinitializationexception?view=netframework-4.8#Static

Comment: I just want to make sure that we are on the same page. The initializers and all connections to the SQL database are stored in the Class1 class. frmSearch is the main for that has the btnSearch button on it. If I try your block of code in Class1, I get the error "Method must have a return type"

Comment: Apologies, I said `frmSearch` when I should have said `Class1`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have implemented this code, but I am still getting the following error message, and the program is jumping passed the try statement to the catch exception: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Search2.exe
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Search2.exe

Comment: The change proposed here can't fix the problem on its own. It allows you to step through the type initialization code more easily to detect where the exception is. You still need to debug it and examine the state.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I will continue to try and debug the issue.

Comment: This is the portion of code that is being skipped. I found this out using the debugging feature. DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                ds = astudent.GetStudents(studid, fname, lname);

                // populate the datagrid with dataset
                dgvStudents.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

Comment: That makes sense to me. The static initializers in `Class1` will run as soon as the class is first "touched"--which happens on the line before you instantiate the `DataSet`. If you're still stuck, try the suggestions from Christopher's answer--replace your static members with either instance or local variables. Following the IDisposable pattern is also a good idea, although I don't think it's the source or solution to your problem. Based on what I've seen here, I think the actual problem is (as others have suggested) with assignment of `connString`.

Comment: @xander I have upgraded to vs19 and now have a more detailed exception: "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)"